# How to implement a 2 to n relation tables

Tags: mysql, database, sqlite, database-design

I'm implementing an app which calculates the points of the players during a championship. In the database, I have a table for players and a table for matches, each match has '2' players, and a player can play 'n' matches.

Should I put 2 columns 'player1' and 'player2' in the table match or create another table match_players with references to match and players?

Comment: Does the match table contains anything else besides the players?

Comment: No, it only has an id and players id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You’re doing the right thing by thinking about this design issue. The rule for first normal form (1NF) says, no repeating fields and that’s generally but not always a good rule.

When there is a repeating field but the number of repeats is definitely fixed, that aspect of 1NF is overkill.

You could have a match table with player1, player2, score1 and score2 for example and that would be just fine.

You could also have a match table, and a player_match table that has one record per player for each match, and fields for the player’s ID and score. In this approach you’d need some extra logic to ensure exactly 2 players per game, assuming that’s important.

Although I respect 1NF as a design principle, engineering is mostly about judgment. If you judge that a change away from having two players is unlikely, or can be accommodated easily if that ever happens, and that it’s easier to ensure correctness (2 and only 2 players per match) using the flattened table design, by all means do that.

Comment: i totally agree on the last statement, design can also depending on what a RDMS supports from the SQL standard .. if a RDMS for example supports `CHECK (with subquery)/ CREATE ASSERTION` from ISO SQL-92 then you can consider using "`1NF`" (normalisation) as you can limit the players per match native in the database.. Or most RDMS supports triggers which can be used the same..

Comment: Correction about 1NF. 1NF states that values in an attribute are to be atomical. What you mean in your answer is 2NF.